# Moving Wordpress from MAMP to WAMP, can't access pages

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wamp, mamp

Before I started working on my website on local with MAMP, I changed Apache Port from 8888 to 80 and that's because I don't want to replace the domaine in the database from http://localhost:8888 to http://localhost when I move it from my Mac to windows.

When I moved it, I went to local host and found my directory, when I clicked it I got "404 not found".. 
I entered "localhost/MSGIE" on the browser and there it is, but I can only access into the dashboard and see the homepage and ERROR: 404 for all the pages.

I think it has something with permalink so I deleted .htacess file, that didn't solve it.

MAMP Ports:

```
Apache Port : 80
Ngix Port :   7888
MySQL port : 3306
```

phpmyadmin in Mac :

```
Database server

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.42 - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Web server

Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.23 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zd DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 15d5c781cfcad91193dceae1d2cdd127674ddb3e $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.5.23
```

PHPMYADMIN in windows :

```
Serveur de base de données

Serveur : mysql wampserver (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
Type de serveur : MySQL
Version du serveur : 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Version du protocole : 10
Utilisateur : root@localhost
Jeu de caractères du serveur : UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Serveur web

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Version du client de base de données : libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
Extension PHP : mysqli
```

Any sort of help is really appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Make things simpler, make sure nothing is using the ports, install a fresh WAMP, add your website, and make sure the root directory is pointing to your htdocs and not some default website.

Comment: Yes I'm using WAMP for the first time and I checked that.. it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by going to

`WAMP tray -> Apache -> Apache modules -> rewrite_module`

another alternative is Going to the apache folder, the to “conf” folder. Locate the httpd.conf file. Searching for a line like :

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Simply get rid of # in front of it.